# MVC - ActionLink looks for a view instead of calling of controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, actionlink, fileresult

I would like to create link on my site, which, after click, would open download window (just some simple text file). In several tutorials I found a way to do it, however, for some reason, it seems that ActionLink doesnt call my method and looks for a view instead

My ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("here is the gpx log", "Download", "Treks")
```

My Download method in Treks controller (added also following method using attribute routing in case it the case of the mess)

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"~/Files/file.txt");
    string fileName = "file.txt"; //I will add parameters later, once the basics work
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}


[Route("treks/{trekname}")] //Route: /Users/12
public ActionResult ShowTrek(string trekname) 
{
    return View(trekname);
}
```

And this is the error I always get

> The view 'Download' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched..
>
> ~/Views/Treks/DownloadFiles.aspx  blahblahbla:

I spent one hour working on this and still not an inch closer to the solution. Does anybody know where I am making a mistake? Thanks a lot

Update: This is the content of my RouteConfig file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );  
   }
```

Edit: Ok, I debugged it. Seems the problem is in attribute routing. For some reason, controller ignored Download method and goes directly for ActionResult ShowTrek... any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I just create a simple MVC application, do something like you and it's works fine(can route to Download and response a file). Try to check your routing config.

Comment: Hi, I dont remember deleting some stuff from my routing config, only change I made there was that I enabled Attribute routing (I use attribute routing in the controller, but only after Download method). I added content of my RouteConfig file into the question.

Comment: Your `ShowTrek` method would throw an exception because its would be trying to find a view with the name equal to the parameter `trekname` (which I assume is "Download"). You need to use `return View((object)trekname);` or better return a model with a property for `trekname`

Comment: Thanks, I will do it - problem was truly with attribute routing. Or move Download function to another controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was in attribute routing. Pls see answer of Stephen Muecke in comments

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Fileresult` with `FileStreamResult` 
you may also need to  create filestream object inside your method

```
new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)

public FileStreamResult Download()
{
 // Your code

}
```